# Cannot compile java file using javac command under JDK on ubuntu (APARAPI)

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, terminal, aparapi

I have run the same command under windows using the windows Java Development Kit and it worked.Now i try to run it ubuntu and i get this error.Please help

[image]

Comment: You'll need the linux SDK; the Windows SDK won't work on Linux.

Comment: I have already installed the jdk within terminal

Comment: `dist_windows_x86_64` is not going to work on Linux.

Comment: i still get the same error after downloading the linux version..

Comment: Please don't post your shell output as screen shots.  Cut-and-paste the text into the question..

Answer (score 0):

Different OS have different dist package manager, you try to install Java environment in your Linux  system by below [Reference](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get)

Comment: My jdk is already installed and working.thats not where the issue is

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are specifying the `-cp` argument incorrectly.

On Linux, the path separator character is `":"` not `";"`.  The `";"` character  separates commands on the command line, assuming that you are using bash or similar as your shell.

It looks like your command has been interpreted as two commands:

```
$ javac -g -cp ../dist_windows_x86_64/something
$ . GPUGalaxySim.java
```

The `javac` command fails because there are no source filenames on that command line ... just like the error message says.

Then the second command:

- The dot command (`"."`) is a built-in shell command that "sources" a file and attempts to interpret it as shell commands.
- If you attempt to "source" a file that is actually Java source code, you get nonsense error messages, basically because the shell has no clue what Java code means.

Comment: Thank you.By following your corrections I did manage to compile the files.Now.however,I am getting this error:

SEVERE: Check your environment. Failed to load aparapi native library aparapi_x86_64 or possibly failed to locate opencl native library (opencl.dll/opencl.so). Ensure that both are in your PATH (windows) or in LD_LIBRARY_PATH (linux).
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at GPUGalaxySim.main(GPUGalaxySim.java:53)